# error C2819: type 'Robot::Animation' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, ogre3d

I cannot for the heck of it find why this is throwing an error!  Okay so I have a Struct that contains some objects.  I then create a pointer to that struct and set the items one by one.  By I keep getting an error.  Here's the code:

**Robot.h:**

```
// Name and Animation info
std::map<std::string, Ogre::AnimationState*> mAnims2;

struct Animation {
    std::string name;   // The name of the animation state
    Ogre::AnimationState* mAnimState;   // The actual animation state
    bool FADE_IN;       // Fade the animation in
    bool FADE_OUT;      // Fade the animation out
};
```

**Robot.cpp:**

```
    // Go through the set by using iterator
while (animStateIter.hasMoreElements()) {
    // The Animation object we will construct
    Animation* mAnimation = new Animation();
    // Initial values for Fading In and Out
    mAnimation->FADE_IN = false;    
    mAnimation->FADE_OUT = false;   
    // Create the Animation object, using the next animation in the list
    mAnimation->mAnimState = animStateIter.getNext();
    // Set the animations name
    mAnimation->name = Animation->mAnimState->getAnimationName();
    // Make sure the animation is set to Loop
    mAnimation->mAnimState->setLoop( true );
    // Insert the Animation object into the list of Animations
    mAnims2.insert( std::make_pair( mAnimation->name, mAnimation) );
    /* DEBUG */
    output << mAnimation->name << std::endl;
}
```

**The Error:**

`Error  1   error C2819: type 'Robot::Animation' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'   c:\users\masry\school-work\fall-2010\cs-425\homework-4\gameengine_solution\robot.cpp    52`

Also if you noticed, I am trying to dynamically create Struct objects and insert them into a Map.  I call:

```
Animation* mAnimation = new Animation();
```

in a while loop, is this good OO design?  If not, what is a better way?  Thank you.

**EDIT:**
So, thanks to Frédéric, it turned out that I was missing a letter.  but now I am getting an error saying:

```
Error   17  error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::string'    c:\users\masry\school-work\fall-2010\cs-425\homework-4\gameengine_solution\robot.cpp    58
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is there:

```
// Set the animations name
mAnimation->name = Animation->mAnimState->getAnimationName();
```

That probably should be:

```
// Set the animations name
mAnimation->name = mAnimation->mAnimState->getAnimationName();
```

Comment: @Free Lance, you're welcome. Note that syntax highlighting can help a lot in those cases, maybe you'll want to use that feature more often :)

Comment: Well now I get an error saying: Error 17 error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::string' c:\users\masry\school-work\fall-2010\cs-425\homework-4\gameengine_solution\robot.cpp 58

Comment: What's `output` in your last line?

Comment: oops.. it's supposed to be a std::stringstream

Comment: sometimes i seriously wanna shoot myself..  Anyways how do I turn on Code highlighting I didn't know how.  I used "Insert Code"